# Arcpy problem: from .py script to .exe file (DLL load failed)

Tags: exe, arcgis, dllimport, esri, arcpy

**PLEASE HELP**
I am trying to convert my .py script into a .exe file so it can be run on any computer (with the arcgis desktop active license), so to do that I am using Pyinstaller == 3.6.
I can create the .exe file but when I want to run the program the next error message drop me up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prueba_1.py", line 12, in 
import arcpy
File "c:\python27\arcgis10.8\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "arcpy_*init*_.py", line 22, in 
File "c:\python27\arcgis10.8\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "arcpy\geoprocessing_*init*_.py", line 14, in 
File "c:\python27\arcgis10.8\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
File "arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 14, in 
File "c:\python27\arcgis10.8\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 680, in load_module
module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
**ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.**
[12632] Failed to execute script prueba_1

some other specifications are: ArcGis Desktop 10.8, Windows 11 and python 2.7.16.

I am trying to convert my .py script into a .exe file so it can be run on any computer (with the arcgis desktop active license), so to do that I am using Pyinstaller == 3.6.
I can create the .exe file but when I want to run the program the next error message drop me up